# How to split a string column in two in Flux (InfluxDB)

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I have a column of `#datatype` `string` which is called `names` and contains the following info for each row:

```
ABV,BVA
BAC,DWA
ZZA,DSW
  ...
```

My question is how can I split (by the comma `,`) this column into two columns with names (`names_1` and `names_2`), such that I will get something like this:

```
names_1    names_2
ABV        BVA
BAC        DWA
ZZA        DSW
      ...
```

I tried [`strings.split()`](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/flux/stdlib/strings/split/) but it only works on an single string. So maybe I need a way to do apply this code to a whole column:

```
import "strings"

data
  |> map (fn:(r) => strings.split(v: r.names, t: ","))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
import "experimental/array"
import "strings"

array.from(rows: [{value: "A,B"}])
  |> map(fn: (r) => {
    parts = strings.split(v: r.value, t: ",")
    return {first: parts[0], second: parts[1]}
  })
```

The `array.from()` can be replaced with `from()` to read data from influxdb. The map function expects a record to be returned. If you have some data that might not have two values after the split, you can also do:

```
import "experimental/array"
import "strings"

array.from(rows: [{value: "A,B"}])
  |> map(fn: (r) => {
    parts = strings.split(v: r.value, t: ",")
    return if length(arr: parts) > 1 then
      {first: parts[0], second: parts[1]}
    else {first: parts[0], second: ""}
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

Your original attempt was almost fine.

This way it should split the column:

```
import "strings"
data
  |> map (fn:(r) => ({
  r with
  names_1: strings.split(v: r.name, t: ",")[0],
  names_2: strings.split(v: r.name, t: ",")[1]
  }))
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the Grafana 8.2.1. I tried and gives me compilation error on names_1: